# int array is overwriting another int array

Tags: c++

I'm working on a calculator to help develop my C++ skills.

At the current time, I'm working on implementing a method to find parenthesis, and break problems down into one operation at a time. But an int array that I'm using to store the position of opening parenthesis is being partially overwritten by the array for closing parenthesis.

I figure I may have a typo or done something in a way that overwrites it. This would likely be a simple solution, but here I am having created an account just for this question after spending hours trying and failing to fix this bug.

TL;DR: the most frustrating "simple" bug I've encountered yet.

```cpp
void Parenth(string datin){
    int x = datin.length() - 1;
    char u;
    int acc[] = {0,0};
    int acc1[] = {0,0};
    int open[4];
    int close[4];
    int size[4];
    for(int i = 0; i <= x; i++){
        u = datin[i];
        if(u == '('){
            open[acc[0]] = i;
            acc[0]++;
        }else if(u == ')'){
            close[acc1[0]] = i;
            acc1[0]++;
        }
    }
    Arrout(open);
    Arrout(close);
    Arrout(size);
    int* by = open;
    int* pass = close;
    int* din = size;
    Flip(pass);
    Arrout(close);
    FindSize(by, pass, din);
    Arrout(size);
    Equation comp;
    comp = Compactor(by, pass, din); 
    int cmpsiz[] = {comp.tier.size,comp.tier2.size,comp.tier3.size,comp.tier4.size,comp.tier5.size};
    Arrout(cmpsiz);

}
```

`Arrout` is a just method I made to loop through an array and log it to the console.

Here is the input to console:

```
0(2(4(6(8(10+12)))))
```

And here is the output I receive:

```
193579       
1516171819   
2106421904015
1918171615   
4151296      
4151296
```

Here is the intended output:

```
13579
1516171819
2106421904015
1918171615
18151296
18151296
```

And yes, I'm aware of how unoptimized at least some of this is.
Most of it is for the purpose of trying desperately to see if something dumb would fix it.

Comment: `open` is an array of `4` integers. Your sample input has 5 `(`s. How do you expect to fit them all in there?

Comment: @NathanPierson C++ is zero indexed correct? Because to my understanding that means it should fit.

Comment: A size 4 array is still size 4 regardless of whether it starts at 0 and runs to 3 or starts at 1 and runs to 4.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that variable `u` is pointless. Just use the value directly: `if (datin[i] == '(') ... else if (datin[i] == ')') ...`.

Comment: Zero indexing does not mean an array with dimension `4` has elements `0` through to `4`.   It means it has element `0` through to `3`.

Comment: regardless of the zero indexing thing I've tried it before with an array size of 10, and then retried at with five after the comment a moment ago it hasn't worked whether i set it to 4,5,6,7,8 or 10.

Comment: And this part of why this bug has been such a pain i've tried numerous solutions from changing array size separating the for loop into two different loops an array used as an accumulator or two separate int accumulators or even the ridiculous dual int array accumulator setup that is shown in this post.

Comment: @Ndev Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger yet to see *exactly* where the code's behavior differs from your expectations? Also, your outputs are very hard to read, you should consider putting some whitespace between the array elements.

Comment: The problem is caused by the out of bounds access. You get the expected output if you don't write out of bounds: https://wandbox.org/permlink/swSLD26dhsaNIoRv You get the actual output if you write out of bounds: https://wandbox.org/permlink/tyzQSss3fSdEyb6C

Comment: @RemyLebeau the first output is the only one that actually comes out incorrect the bottom two outputs are just the difference between the location of closing and opening parenthesis. and the problem is likely in the for loop or array declarations as I've tested Arrout gone back and double and triple checked that it isn't modifying the output or logging it in the wrong order.

Comment: `close[4] = i;` overwrites the first value of `open`. Another solution: Use the correct sizes for the arrays: https://wandbox.org/permlink/WFs4aqprIrDYyudQ

Comment: Figured it out declaring open, close,  and size arrays with 6 for array size fixed it but when all three were 5 or 4 it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The arrays have size 4 but you're writing 5 elements into them. Writing out of bounds into an array causes undefined behavior.

Use containers with dynamic size:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::string;

template<std::size_t N>
void Arrout(int (&arr)[N]) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void Arrout(const std::vector<int> &vec) {
    for (const auto el : vec) {
        std::cout << el;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void Parenth(string datin){
    int x = datin.length();
    char u;
    int acc[] = {0,0};
    int acc1[] = {0,0};
    std::vector<int> open;
    std::vector<int> close;
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        u = datin[i];
        if(u == '('){
            open.push_back(i);
            acc[0]++;
        }else if(u == ')'){
            close.push_back(i);
            acc1[0]++;
        }
    }
    Arrout(open);
    Arrout(close);
}

int main() {
    Parenth("0(2(4(6(8(10+12)))))");
}
```

If you really have to use fixed sized arrays increase the array sizes to:

```
int open[5];
int close[5];
```

That's a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;

template<std::size_t N>
void Arrout(int (&arr)[N]) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void Parenth(string datin){
    int x = datin.length();
    char u;
    int acc[] = {0,0};
    int acc1[] = {0,0};
    int open[5];
    int close[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
        u = datin[i];
        if(u == '('){
            open[acc[0]] = i;
            acc[0]++;
        }else if(u == ')'){
            close[acc1[0]] = i;
            acc1[0]++;
        }
    }
    Arrout(open);
    Arrout(close);
}

int main() {
    Parenth("0(2(4(6(8(10+12)))))");
}
```

Comment: Since the input `string` is dynamic, it would be better to implement `open` and `close` using dynamic arrays, like with `std::vector`.

Comment: Rather than `int x = datin.length() - 1;` and incur issues when `datin.length() == 0`, perhaps use  `int x = datin.length(); ... for(int i = 0; i <  x; i++){`.